# How can you exclude files in php?

Tags: php, background

im using php to include background colors, so that users can change them, but i also need to know how to exclude them, or i need to know if it will automatically change once they hit the new page to include them i do this:

```
<?php include('background.php') 
?>
```

Comment: If you do not know how to accept an Answer let us know we will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you can include the file in PHP. But there is a way which can help you to solve your problem.

You can use same variable names in both files.
e.g.
Once you include first file i.e.

```
include("file1.php");
```

which has

```
<?php
$color1 = "red";
?>
```

Then if you may include second file may be

```
include("file2.php");
```

which has

```
<?php
$color1 = "blue";
?>
```

This will replace the first variable value **red** with **blue** color.

So anyways this way your new background colors will be seen.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is scripting language, that means its interpreted not compiled, so for each request it will be interpreted again.

If you included something in your previous request using some condition, and your condition is false in next request those files will not be included.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, the included files are usually included on a per-request base. So if you `include 1.php` in the first request and `include 2.php` in the second request, the second request does not know that the previous request did `include 1.php`.

If you mean to un-include a file during a single request, no I do not think that would be possible.